# Java: Trying To Get User Input As Int In Simon Game

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to figure out why 1) my Simon game hangs up after saying "Enter A Number"- it doesn't look like it even gets past validation. I'm trying to get user input, and check to see if that was the right number to press at that time. 2) Also, it used to generate a random number but when the user pressed it, it came back as false for some reason. Some other random number would pass though. 3) Also, is the code below color coded for you? Thanks guys.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class Simon extends Program implements ActionListener
{

Scanner usersInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);


private int array[];
private int currentSeqLength;
private int usersInput;
private String usersInputString;


public Simon()
{
    //Initialize Class Values
    array = new int[20];
    currentSeqLength = 1;
    usersInput = 0;

    generateSequence();

    while(currentSeqLength < array.length)
    {
        playSequence();

        //Wait For User's Input, Assign To Variable
        System.out.println("Enter A Number");
        usersInput = usersInputScanner.nextInt();

        if (pushButton(usersInput) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("You Entered: " + usersInput);

            currentSeqLength++;
        }

        else
        {

            gameOverMessage();
            break;

            //Reset Variables:

        }

    }


}




//----------------------- Methods Here On Down -----------------------------





public void generateSequence()
{

    //Fill Array With Random Numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*4);

    }


}

public void setLength(int length)
{
    //Set Current Length To Size Of Given Argument
    currentSeqLength = length;

}

int getLength()
{
    return currentSeqLength;

}

int[] playSequence()
{
    //Print Out The Current Sequence

    //New Local Array To Return
    int newArray[]= new int[currentSeqLength];


    //Repeat As Many Times As Value Of currentSeqLength
    for(int i = 0; i < currentSeqLength ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);

        //Return an array of int's to the player. 
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    }

    return newArray;
}

boolean pushButton(int usersInput)
{
    //Given A Button Press (0-3), Return Whether That Was The 
        //Correct Button To Play At The Moment

    if (usersInput == array[currentSeqLength])
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}


boolean isTurnOver()
{
    //If Current Sequence Length Matches Or Exceeds Value Of 
        //Array Element In Location Of Current Sequence Length

    if (currentSeqLength >= array[currentSeqLength])
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

//Not Needed?
boolean isGameOver()
{
    if (pushButton(usersInput) == false)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

String gameOverMessage()
{
    return "Game Over";
}

/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    int input;


}
*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code is colour-coded for me.

Comment: Hi @firingblanks, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) my Simon game hangs up after saying "Enter A Number"- it doesn't
>   look like it even gets past validation.

It's working fine, but you need to `System.out.println` the string that is returned from `gameOverMessage()`.  Right now, it runs perfectly but there's no output to the console, so it looks unresponsive (and it's not hanging, it just reaches the end of execution, and stops).

```
else {
    gameOverMessage();
    break;
}
```

should be

```
else {
    System.out.println(gameOverMessage());
}
```

> 2) Also, it used to generate a random number but when the user pressed
>   it, it came back as false for some reason.

I'm not getting this behavior in your sample code, it looks like it works as expected.

> 3) Also, is the code below color coded for you?

Yep, the preview box on SO sometimes takes a second to do the syntax highlighting.  It works fine though.

Incidentally, 3 questions in one is a bit of a slog for the answerer.  In the future perhaps try to limit yourself to one :)